# Modprobe: 'Invalid nodule format', yet works after insmod

Tags: 12.04, kernel, modprobe

I am having a problem with Ubuntu 12.04 not properly recognising a custom made kernel module. The kernel module is a spoof of `raw1394`. So that programs that look for the presence of a `raw1394` module in memory still work properly, even though the actual module that handles IEEE 1394/FireWire communication is different. The instructions for creating the dummy raw1394 module are at [wiki.sofa-framework.org](https://wiki.sofa-framework.org/tdev/wiki/HowTo/SensableWithoutRaw1394).

The problem is that to load the kernel module I have to use `insmod` every time.

When after rebooting I try to load the `raw1394` kernel module I get the following error message:

```
$ sudo modprobe raw1394
FATAL: Error inserting raw1394 (/lib/modules/3.5.0-51-generic/misc/raw1394.ko): Invalid module format
```

However, if I run the following sequence of commands it all works fine:

```
$ sudo insmod raw1394.ko
$ sudo modprobe raw1394
```

I can't see how it can be a problem with mismatched version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mech801 3.5.0-51-generic #77~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 5 00:48:28 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here are the MD5 hashes. The files are the same length but I assume that `insmod` must be changing something internally as it inserts the module. Both files are 3274 bytes in size.

```
$ md5sum /lib/modules/3.5.0-51-generic/misc/raw1394.ko ./raw1394.ko 
ab06501bba1372f57115125bc7a24dfb  /lib/modules/3.5.0-51-generic/misc/raw1394.ko
c3c3d2b4e2fe174a76b90af33eefc5e0  ./raw1394.ko
```

Is there something I am missing that is causing this `Invalid module format` problem?